# Querying/Selecting rows from Parent Entity when using Hibernate JOINED inheritence strategy

Tags: java, hibernate

I know there are three types of inheritence strategies: **SINGLE_TABLE, TABLE_PER_CLASS, JOINED**. I think the best choice is **JOINED** if I want my underlying database to be normalized. However, let us consider this usecase: I have a Parent Entity and one Child Entity that extends this Parent Entity. The inheritence strategy I am using is **JOINED**. Now, from the front-end of the application I can add Parent and Child entities. When I do search from front-end to get all Child Entities I am able to get all the Child Entities. Now, when I try to do a search only on Parent Entity I see that the result set contains all the entities(Parent + Child) and I understand why this is happening. My question is that is there any way we can search/query for only Parent entities(excluding rows from Child entity) when I am using the JOINED inheritence startegy?

Comment: When you say 'B extends A', it is supposed to mean 'B can be used wherever A is expected'. That's the whole point of inheritance. If, in some scenario, A can be used but B cannot, then inheritance is probably not the proper way to model the relationship between A and B

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Hibernate optimize this, but you have to make sure you are not selecting the entity or use fields of the parent table.